# pt-show-grant and root password protection

Tags: cron, password-protection, percona

There is a way to use pt-show-grant in crontab without using root password?
In general it's possible (mysql and mariadb) to specify the "default password" to use.

```
[client]
password                       = mypassword
```

But in this case pt-show-grant seems ignoring all cnf files.